# Error when call the array:Every row given must be either null or an array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am trying to call the array from `data.php` file  to javascript file `script.js` and I am using this method `$.get` but I got this error: `Every row given must be either null or an array.`

this is the code in data.php:

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$database = " ";
$username = " ";
$password = " ";

$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if (!$connect) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$query = 'SELECT * FROM climate';

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>

<?php 

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo " 
             ['".$row['time']."',".$row['temp'].",".$row['hum']."],";
    }
}
?>
```

and in script.js:

```
function drawLineColors() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Humidity');

    $.get("data.php", function(sensors){
        data.addRows([sensors]);
        let rowIndex = data.getNumberOfRows() - 1; //gets the row index of last row
        let lastTime = data.getValue(rowIndex, 0); //gets the first column
        let lastTemp = data.getValue(rowIndex, 1); //gets second column
        let lastHum = data.getValue(rowIndex,2); //gets third column

        $("#tempr > .content").html(lastTemp + " &deg;C");
        $("#humr > .content").text(lastHum + " %");
```

which I want to call the array through `data.addRows([sensors]);`

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**

Comment: Dont try and build your own JSON, [use `json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)